# ACL permission in amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor, acl, bucket

I can upload images in Amazon s3 bucket from meteor but when i go to check ( {my-bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{filename} ) it give me access denied error.

Here is the configuration code -

```
S3.config = {
    key: 'amazons3key',
    secret: 'amazons3keysecret',
    bucket: 'my-bucket',
    acl: 'public-read-write' 
    };
```

Is this correct or i am missing something here?

I can access the same file if i log in to amazon s3 and change file permission their

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several hours in this issue i finally found the answer.

You have to change bucket policy in Amazon. Under permissions/add bucket policy add this code -

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
         },
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure you replace bucket in arn:aws:s3:::bucket/* with your bucket name.This example will give read access to Everyone on all files in your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to check

- What are the permissions at bucket level ?
- How are you checking your bucket ?

If you put the bucket address in a browser, the HTTP call will be unauthenticated.
You can use signed URL to prove your identity to S3, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html (same apply to other languages)